# R Shiny working locally but not on server

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I've installed all library dependencies, and when I ran `is.shiny.appobj(shinyApp(ui,server))` it returns TRUE.

I do have some files that I'm calling in, but they're of the format `"file.csv"`, which from my research is meant to help things.

Exact error message: `app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object.`

The basics of what I'm trying to do is call in a file, run it through some other files to get outputs, and return the original file with an updated format and some new values. I've also added the feature of when you select the rows, it adds up one of the columns, using the package DT.

Here's my UI code with libraries:

```
library(shiny)
library(rsconnect)
library(lubridate)
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
library(DT)

ui=fluidPage(
  fileInput(inputId = "bill",label="Select Bill"), #choose bill
  downloadLink("downloadbill", "Download Bill"),
  hr(),
  h5("Total for Selected Rows :"),
  textOutput("dateTotal"),
  DT::dataTableOutput('table')
)
```

Here's my server code:

```
server<-function(input,output){
  observe({
    req(input$bill)


    ####Load in CSV files####

    drugs=read.csv("updateddrugs.csv")
    #loading similar files

    ####Find code in row input####

    findcode<- function (rowinput) {
      column7.output=""
      if (as.character(rowinput[1])!=""){
        code=as.character(rowinput[3])
        codedate=substr(as.character(rowinput[1]),1,10)
        units=as.character(rowinput[6])
        charges=as.character(rowinput[7])
        column7.output=OMFS(codedate,code,units,charges)}
      return(column7.output)
    }

    ####OMFS type####

    OMFS <-function (codedate,code,units,charges) {
      parsed.date<-mdy(codedate)
      OMFS.amount=0.00
      OMFS.temp=0.00
      if (startsWith(code,"99070")){ #drug code
        OMFS.temp=search.drugs(code)

        if(nchar(OMFS.temp)==0){
          OMFS.amount=parse_number(charges)
        }
        else{
          OMFS.amount=OMFS.temp
        }
        return(OMFS.amount)
      }
      else{

        if(startsWith(code,"ML") | startsWith(code, "ml")){ #med legal code
          OMFS.amount=parse_number(charges)
        }
        else{
          if(startsWith(code,"WC")|startsWith(code,"wc")){
            if (year(parsed.date)>2013){
              if (year(parsed.date)==2014){
                OMFS.amount=wcprice$X2014[wcprice$code==code]
              }
              if (year(parsed.date)==2015){
                OMFS.amount=wcprice$X2015[wcprice$code==code]
              }
              if (year(parsed.date)==2016){
                OMFS.amount=wcprice$X2016[wcprice$code==code]
              }
              if (year(parsed.date)==2017){
                OMFS.amount=wcprice$X2017[wcprice$code==code]
              }
              if (year(parsed.date)==2018){
                OMFS.amount=wcprice$X2018[wcprice$code==code]
              }
              if (year(parsed.date)==2019){
                OMFS.amount=wcprice$X2019[wcprice$code==code]
              }
            }
          }

          else{
            OMFS.temp=search.OMFS(parsed.date,substr(code,1,5),units)
            if(is.na(OMFS.temp)||nchar(OMFS.temp)==0 || OMFS.temp==0.00){
              OMFS.amount=parse_number(charges)
            }
            else{
              OMFS.amount=OMFS.temp
            }
          }}
        return(OMFS.amount)
      }

    }


    ####searching for OMFS is CSV files####

    search.OMFS<-function(codedate,code,units){
      pre2014span<-seq.Date(from=as_date("2000-01-01"),to=as_date("2013-12-31"),by="day")
      weird2007span<-seq.Date(from=as_date("2007-02-15"),to=as_date("2013-12-31"),by="day")
      #and similar spans

      if (codedate %in% pre2014span){
        if(code %in% blood$V1){
          price=blood[blood$V1==code,2]
          price2=price*as.numeric(units)
        }

        else{
          if (codedate %in% weird2007span & code %in% weird2007codes$V1){
            price=weird2007codes[weird2007codes$V1==code,2]
            price2=price*as.numeric(units)
          }
          else{
            price=OMFS2003 %>% filter(V2==code) %>% select(V7)
            price=as.numeric(as.character(price[[1]]))
            if (length(price>1)){price=max(price)}
            units=as.numeric(units)
            price2=price*units
            }

        }
        return(as.character(price2))
      }
      #similar conditional statements for span dates
    }

    ####searching for drug codes####

    search.drugs <-function(code){ #OMFS for drugs
      smallcode=gsub(".*-","",code)
      price=drugs %>% filter(Column2==smallcode) %>% select(PRICE)
      price=as.numeric(as.character(price[[1]]))
      return(price)
    }

    ####payments####
    paymentsmade<-function(bill,CalculatedOMFSColumn){
      for (i in 1: nrow(bill)){
        if (startsWith(as.character(bill[i,7]),"($")){
          CalculatedOMFSColumn[i]=parse_number(as.character(bill[i,7]))*-1
        }
      }
      return(CalculatedOMFSColumn)
    }

    ###################
    ####loadingbill####

    tempbill=(input$bill) #call in bill

    showModal(modalDialog("Please wait while your bill is processing.", footer=NULL)) #starting loading message

    bill=read.csv(tempbill$datapath,colClasses = "character") #read bill
    smallerbill=bill[,1:15]
    smallerbill<-as.data.frame(smallerbill)
    payments=(smallerbill[,10:15])
    charges=(smallerbill[,1:9])

    newnames<-c("X.1","X.2","X.3","X.4","X.6","X.7")
    colnames(payments)<-newnames
    payments$ID<-seq.int(nrow(payments))
    payments$X.5<-c("")
    payments$X.8<-c("")
    payments$X<-c("")

    charges$ID<-seq.int(nrow(charges))

    newbill<-rbind(payments,charges)

    newbill<-arrange_at(newbill,"ID")
    newbill1<-newbill[,order(colnames(newbill))]
    newbill1$ID<-NULL

    newbill1$X.8<-NULL

    colnamesbill<-c("DOS","DOE","Procedue","Modifier","Description","Unit","Charges","Total Charges")

    colnames(newbill1)<-colnamesbill

    newbill1<-newbill1 %>% filter(Charges!="")


    OMFSColumn<-apply(newbill1,1,findcode) #generate OMFS column

    updatedwithPayments<-paymentsmade(newbill1,OMFSColumn)

    updatedwithPay<-vapply(updatedwithPayments,paste, collapse=",", character(1L))

    newbill1$OMFS=updatedwithPay

    outputbill<-renderDataTable(newbill1)
    removeModal() #remove loading message

    output$table<-outputbill

    output$dateTotal=renderText({ #outputs the total for the selected rows
      s=input$table_rows_selected
      return(sum(as.numeric(newbill1[s,9])))

    })

    output$downloadbill<-downloadHandler(
      filename = "patientname.csv",
      content = function(filename) {
        write.csv(newbill1, filename, row.names = FALSE)
      }
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server = server)
```

I'm open to any suggestions!!!

Comment: It works fine on my setup - just when I run `is.shiny.appobj(ui,server)` I get 
`Error in is.shiny.appobj(ui, server) : unused argument (server)`

Comment: sorry, i meant ```is.shiny.appobj(shinyApp(ui,server))``` returns TRUE

Comment: You can try splitting in ui.R and server.R as in [this issue](https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno/issues/61)

Comment: I had hoped to find a solution aside from that, but spliting the ui and server is the only solution at this time. Thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @HubertL, splitting the server and ui was the answer. If there are any other solutions that people come up with I'd be happy to hear them!